# Implementing a UIApplicationShortcutItem

Tags: ios, uikit, 3dtouch, uiapplicationshortcutitem

I was looking at the `UIKit` framework reference and came across [`UIApplicationShortcutItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationShortcutItem_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplicationShortcutItem/localizedTitle). It is for 3D Touch.

It contains this code sample:

```
let existingShortcutItems = UIApplication.sharedApplication().shortcutItems ?? []
let anExistingShortcutItem = existingShortcutItems[anIndex]
var updatedShortcutItems = existingShortcutItems
let aMutableShortcutItem = anExistingShortcutItem.mutableCopy() as! UIMutableApplicationShortcutItem
aMutableShortcutItem.localizedTitle = “New Title"
updatedShortcutItems[anIndex] = aMutableShortcutItem
UIApplication.sharedApplication().shortcutItems = updatedShortcutItemsode here
```

If I am correct you put this in the app delegate?

And how does this work? Is the `localizedTitle` method called to check the title of the action selected, and then call the action that has that title? Where are the actions held?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've supplied will allow you to create shortcut items (i.e. the UI associated with short cuts that are revealed on the home screen when a user 3D-touches an app icon). To respond to those shortcut items you will need to implement:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
performActionForShortcutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem
  completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded))completionHandler
```

or

```
optional func application( application: UIApplication,
performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem,
           completionHandler completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void)
```

in your UIApplicationDelegate. You can read about it in the [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:performActionForShortcutItem:completionHandler:). But the gist is this method will be called when your app is launched from a shortcut and you can inspect the shortcutItem to perform the appropriate action.